# Does this function use too many checks and variables?

Tags: java, optimization

I'm doing a Udemy course in Java and was tasked with printing different things, based on the equality of the input integers. My solution was correct, but feels too verbose. Is there a more elegant solution?

**Note: This task only allows one function (except their inserted main), so I can't just return from the first check**.

```
public class IntEqualityPrinter {
    // write your code here 
    public static void printEqual(final int a, final int b, final int c) {
        String message = "";
        if(a < 0 || b < 0 || c < 0) {
            message = "Invalid Value";
        } else {
            int count = 0;
            if(a == b) {
                ++count;
            }
            if(b == c) {
                ++count;
            }
            if(a == c) {
                ++count;
            }
            switch(count) {
                case 0:         message = "All numbers are different";          break;
                case 1: case 2: message = "Neither all are equal or different"; break;
                case 3:         message = "All numbers are equal";              break;
            }
        }


        System.out.println( message );
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "elegant"? Can you give a definition that is not subjective? Right now, your question is very opinion-based. I'm sure many people would find your code ok, while many other people would say that it should be improved.

Comment: You never get to the case `count == 2`. (Equality is a transitive property: `if (a == b && b == c) assert a == c;`)

Comment: It can be written in a more compact way, but that way is reasonably easy to read and works okay, so I see no reason to change it.

Comment: " so I can't just return from the first check" that's not true. How about: `if (a < 0 || b < 0 || c < 0) { System.out.println("Invalid Value"); return; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...so I can't just return from the first check.

But, you can! How about:

```
public static void printEqual(final int a, final int b, final int c) {

    if (a < 0 || b < 0 || c < 0) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Value");
        return;
    }

    String message = "";

    if (a == b) {
        if (a == c) {
            message = "All numbers are equal";
        } else {
            message = "Neither all are equal or different";
        }
    } else {
        if (a == c) {
            message = "Neither all are equal or different";
        } else {
            message = "All numbers are different";
        }
    }

    System.out.println(message);
}
```

I guess it is straight forward and combines the checks with the actual initialization of the message.

Comment: I like this one a lot but doesn't it defy DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)? The print and return at the start is perfect though

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of having a switch statement inside the else block, you can just make a check in the following way:

```
else if(a == b && b == c) {
   message = "All numbers are equal";  
}

else if(a != b && b != c && a != c) {
   message = "All numbers are different";  
}

else {
   message = "Neither all are equal or different";
}
```

This way, your code would be more readable

Comment: Your first edit (adding `a!=c`) was necessary, but the second one (adding `a==c`) isn't. Edit: and your third edit undid them all ... how am I supposed to comment on answers if they keep changing ;-)

Comment: Fails for `a = 1, b = 2, c = 1`

Comment: Sorry for quick editting I just saw the error after I posted and quickly editted. Thanks for the comments.